# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Employee.username' in 'where clause'

Tags: sql, cakephp, authentication, controller

I am trying to get my login working with CakePHP 2.4.7 but I seemed to run into a problem. I am using the 'Employees' as the user of the database.

I got this error

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Employee.username' in 'where clause'

and after i changed all my 'username' fields to employee_username, I'm still getting the same error. Could someone please help?

Below is my code for AppController, EmployeeController, Employee and login.ctp:

AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'login'),
        'authError' => 'You must be logged in to view this page.',
        'loginError' => 'Invalid Username or Password entered, please try again.',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
            'fields' => array('username' => 'employee_username', 'password' => 'employee_pw'),
            'userModel'=>'Employee'
            ))

    ));

// only allow the login controllers only
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('login');
}
}
```

EmployeesController:

```
class EmployeesController extends AppController {

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
    //public $components = array('Paginator');
    public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 25,
        'conditions' => array('status' => '1'),
        'order' => array('Employee.employee_username' => 'asc' ) 
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('login','add'); 

    }



    public function login() {

        //if already logged-in, redirect
        if($this->Session->check('Auth.Employee')){
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));      
        }

        // if we get the post information, try to authenticate
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $result = $this->Employee->findByUsername($this->data['Employee']['employee_username']);
            if ($this->Auth->login(/*$result['Employee']*/)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome, '. $this->Auth->user('employee_username')));
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password'));
            }
        } 
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 6,
            'order' => array('Employee.employee_username' => 'asc' )
        );
        $employees = $this->paginate('Employee');
        $this->set(compact('employees'));
    }
```

Employee Model:

```
public $validate = array(
        'id' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'employee_name' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'date_hired' => array(
            'date' => array(
                'rule' => array('date'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        /*'employee_phone_number' => array(
            'phone' => array(
                'rule' => array('phone'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),*/
        'employee_email' => array(
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => array('email'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'employee_dob' => array(
            'date' => array(
                'rule' => array('date'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'access_level' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'employee_username' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'employee_pw' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );
```

login.ctp

```
<div class=“employees form">
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Employee'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?>
        </legend>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('employee_username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: How about something related to the error message, such as the table name and column names?

Comment: Why are you not using login() as documented? Your custom code is highly unconventional and probably quite likely to break at some point.

Comment: You asked similar question before  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337429/cakephp-authentication-login-with-employee-instead-of-user and your problem was on that question that `You have very little experience on AuthComponent`.. Practice by User model a lot and then you can try to use different model.. Well, If you like to solve your present problem, then we have to ask you a lot of question and that will make your question messy..